# Совмещение теории с практикой

Tags: c#

На данный момент я читаю Шилдта по С#. Но как известно, теорию нужно совмещать с практикой и полезно писать учебную программу, которая охватывает несколько тем учебника сразу. Я уже заканчиваю читать главу с событиями. Я выбрал несколько вариантов приложений, которые хочу написать. Бывает, что прочитанную теорию не имеет смысла использовать в программе. А если не практиковаться, прочитанное забывается. Возникает вопрос, как в таком случае совмещать теорию с практикой. Фактически, читаю учебник я каждый день и потом, что то пишу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Писать учебные программы, охватывающие много глав сразу, конечно, полезно. Это научит вас  правильно структурировать программу, обдумывать архитектурные моменты заранее и выработает хороший стиль. **Но вам почти гарантированно не понадобится 80% тонких моментов, которые несёт в себе язык.** И если вашей целью сейчас является именно изучение языка, советую использовать **любую** неясность в книге, как повод обратиться к компилятору.

Например сейчас вы изучаете события. Попробуйте же с помощью компилятора выяснить:

1. Является ли подписка на событие в достижимом объекте спасением от сборщика мусора.
2. Попробуйте реализовать свой "слабые подписки" через делегаты и [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.weakreference.aspx), которые не будут обладать этим свойсвом.
3. Попробуйте подписать одно событие на другое.
4. И пр.

Список задач ограничивается только вашей фантазией.

Answer (score 0):

Любая теория - это основа для практики, база так сказать. Естественно не практикуя что-то это постепенно забываешь. Однако писать учебные программы надо не только для крепкого запоминания теории, но и для вырабатывания мышления на "волне" конкретного языка программирования. Говорят что хорошо запоминаешь разговорные языки тогда, когда начинаешь думать на них!) В программировании также.